# How to delete a section of matplotlib axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to have a plot like the one shown in this figure:
[image: Desired errorbar plot]

Here is my Python3 code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.1,1.1,step=0.1)
y = np.array([0.03,0.03,0.05,0.05,0.06,0.17,0.44,1.37,4.43,6.89])
err = np.array([0.02,0.03,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.23,3.61,4.70,1.2,0.7])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr=err)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes',-0.02))
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('axes',-0.02))

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.0,1.21,0.2))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,11,2))

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

plt.show()
```

From the above code, I get this plot:
[image: Errorbar plot with an unwanted axis section]

If I use `ax.set_ylim([0,10])` instead of `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,11,2))`, I get the following figure having truncated the error bar:
[image: Truncated error bar]

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this demo is helpful? [Spine Placement Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spine_placement_demo.html)

Comment: There is also [Parasite Axes Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/gallery/axisartist/demo_parasite_axes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(0, 10)`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.1,1.1,step=0.1)
y = np.array([0.03,0.03,0.05,0.05,0.06,0.17,0.44,1.37,4.43,6.89])
err = np.array([0.02,0.03,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.23,3.61,4.70,1.2,0.7])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

ax.errorbar(x,y,yerr=err)

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes',-0.02))
ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(0, 10)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.0,1.21,0.2))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,11,2))

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
```

[image]